# Swift 5.1 NSInternalInconsistencyException error

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, avkit

I am updating old media player project (Swift 3) and have weird error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unsupported action method
>   signature. Must return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus or take a
>   completion handler as the second argument.

I get this error on this code:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePrevTrack))

@objc func handlePrevTrack(){
        if playListEpisodes.count == 0 {
            return
        }

        let currentEpisodeIndex = playListEpisodes.firstIndex { (ep) -> Bool in
            return self.episode.title == ep.title && self.episode.author == ep.author
        }

        guard let index = currentEpisodeIndex else { return}
        let nextEpisode:Episode

        if index == 0 {
            nextEpisode = playListEpisodes[playListEpisodes.count - 1]
        }else {
            nextEpisode = playListEpisodes[index - 1]
        }

        self.episode = nextEpisode

 }
```

what changed in Swift 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `previousTrackCommand` selector should take `MPRemoteCommandEvent` as first argument and return `MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus`:

```
func addTarget(handler: (MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) -> Any
```

So your `handlePrevTrack` function should be declared as:

```
@objc func handlePrevTrack(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
...
}
```